# Having trouble getting Django {% regroup %} to work

Tags: python, django

I am trying to work with the `{% regroup %}` template tag to display user made lists with items in them to look like this:

> LIST NAME
>
> Item
>
> Item
>
> Item

Not this (which is the only way I can get it to render atm):

> List Name 1
>
> Item 1
>
> List Name 1
>
> Item 2
>
> List Name 1
>
> Item 3

Based on my reading of the Django Docs I have to turn my queryset into a dictionary but I am having trouble achieving this. I also need to ensure my queryset if filtered based on the logged in user. I am getting errors depending on where I put the values() method, or it currently shows nothing at all...

I also tried following this answer but got no love.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865265/django-regroup-not-working-as-expected)

Here is my views.py

```
class user_playlist(ListView):
    template_name = 'testingland/playlist.html'
    context_object_name = 'playlist'
    model = UserVenue

    def get_queryset(self):
        venue = self.request.GET.get('venue', None)
        list = self.request.GET.get('list', None)
        playlist = UserVenue.objects.filter(list__user=self.request.user)
        return playlist
```

Here is the models:

```
class UserList(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #is this okay?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name

class UserVenue(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(mapCafes, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    list = models.ForeignKey(UserList, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And here is the template (I built it based on reading the Django Docs on [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)).

```
<div class="user_playlists">
{% regroup venue by list as user_playlist %}
  <ul>
      {% for list in user_playlist %}
      <li> {{ list.grouper }}
        <ul>
            {% for place in list.list %}
            <li>{{ place.venue }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424435/how-to-convert-a-django-queryset-to-a-list) answer your question?

Comment: I did review that and see there are similarities but I had trouble applying the solution to my case and thought that as it is 10 years old some newer methods may be available. Short answer: unfortunately it doesn’t (at least for my current experience level).

Comment: Okay ... that makes sense.

Comment: it should be `regroup` playlist not `regroup` venue. `{% regroup playlist by list as user_playlist %}`

Comment: and also I highly advise you not to use the `list` as an identifier. It's a python Built-in Function.

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer. I know it was a stupidly titled model field.